# Problema al Agregar un registro (vuelvee de la vista con ID) C# asp.net core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo un problema que no he podido solucionar. 
Tengo una vista que me permite visualizar los detalles de un determinado Owner y en la misma vista tengo un botón que me llama a la acción del controlador llamada AddPet (la ruta completa hasta aquí es https://localhost:44370/Owners/Details/1).

Al presionar el botón AddPet me lleva a la vista AddPet y ejecuta el GET del controlador

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Addpet(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var owner = await _context.Owners.FindAsync(id.Value);
        if (owner == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var model = new PetViewModel
        {
            Born = DateTime.Today,
            OwnerId = owner.Id,
            PetTypes = _combosHelper.GetComboPetTypes()
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Cómo pueden ver este método regresa a la vista un **PetViewModel**

```
public class PetViewModel : Pet
{
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is mandatory.")]
    [Display(Name = "Pet Type")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "You must select a pet type.")]
    public int PetTypeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PetTypes { get; set; }
}


 public class Pet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} field can not have more than {1} characters.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is mandatory.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} field can not have more than {1} characters.")]
    public string Race { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Born")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is mandatory.")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Born { get; set; }

    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    //TODO: replace the correct URL for the image
    public string ImageFullPath => string.IsNullOrEmpty(ImageUrl)
        ? null
        : $"https://TBD.azurewebsites.net{ImageUrl.Substring(1)}";

    [Display(Name = "Born*")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm}")]
    public DateTime BornLocal => Born.ToLocalTime();

    public PetType PetType { get; set; }
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }
    public ICollection<History> Histories { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Agenda> Agendas { get; set; }

}
```

En el **CONTROLADOR**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Addpet(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var owner = await _context.Owners.FindAsync(id.Value);
        if (owner == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var model = new PetViewModel
        {
            Born = DateTime.Today,
            OwnerId = owner.Id,
            PetTypes = _combosHelper.GetComboPetTypes()
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Addpet(PetViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var path = string.Empty;
            if(model.ImageFile != null)
            {
                 path = await _imageHelper.UploadImageAsync(model.ImageFile);
            }

            var pet = await _converterHelper.ToPetAsync(model, path);
            _context.Pets.Add(pet);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction($"Details/{model.OwnerId}");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

**LA VISTA **

```html
@model MyVet.Web.Models.PetViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<h4>Pet</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Addpet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="OwnerId" />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ImageFile" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ImageFile" class="form-control" type="file" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ImageFile" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PetTypeId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="PetTypeId" asp-items="Model.PetTypes" class="form-control"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="PetTypeId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Race" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Race" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Race" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Born" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Born" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Born" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Remarks" class="control-label"></label>
                <textarea asp-for="Remarks" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="Remarks" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@Model.OwnerId" class="btn btn-success">Back to Owner</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Una vez lleno el formulario y al invocar al POST del controlador, el id de Pet en vez de estar vacío me trae el mismmo numero de Owner al que me encuentro creándole el Pet

No encuentro dónde puede estar el problema 
Me podrán ayudar ? si necesitan algún otro fragmento de código con gusto se los adjunto

Mil gracias

Comment: No entendi cual es el problema, te esta asignando el OwnerId en el valor del Id que recibes en el Addpet() del GET ? el Owner y el Pet son vistas separadas o estan en el mismo controller cargandose como si fueran partial view ?

Comment: Lo que si deberias evitar usar un Addpet() para crear una nueva pet y tambien para editar una existente, eso trae problemas. Crea en el controller un AddPet() sin ningun parametro y otro que sea EditPet(int Id) que cargue la misma view si quieres reusarla enviando un model. Pero que el Add y el Edit esten en action distintos

Answer (score 0):

Debido a que entre el controlador y la vista no hay nada que esté cargando el dato decidí agregar un parámetro en el método que convierte de PetViewModel a Pet

```
public async Task<Pet> ToPetAsync(PetViewModel model, string path, bool isNew)
    {
        var pet = new Pet
        {
            Agendas = model.Agendas,
            Born = model.Born,
            Histories = model.Histories,
            **Id = isNew ? 0 : model.Id,**
            ImageUrl = path,
            Name = model.Name,
            Owner = await _dataContext.Owners.FindAsync(model.OwnerId),
            PetType = await _dataContext.PetTypes.FindAsync(model.PetTypeId),
            Race = model.Race,
            Remarks = model.Remarks
        };

        return pet;
    }
```

Cuando estoy agregando un campo lo mando en true y cuando estoy editando lo mando en false 
Saludos

Comment: Deberia editar la pregunta, entiendo esto no seria una respuesta